# ErrorException Undefined variable: slot (View: D:\xampp8\htdocs\cshaper\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

ErrorException
Undefined variable: slot (View: D:\xampp8\htdocs\cshaper\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

go to layouts > guest.blade.php remove this line :

```
 {{ $slot }}
```

i hope it was useful !